# How to move Grid programmatically

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a Grid in my application and I want to move it around using four buttons (up, down, left, right). I have the grid's position (X and Y), but I don't know how to set a new position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the keyboard down event, you can change the Margin property of the grid.  This will work best if you have the grid nested within another Grid or Canvas.  You have the keep the parent container in mind and how it will work with the layout.

Assuming it is nested in another Grid control, here is a sample of what the code might look like:

```
private void OnKeyDown( object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e )
{
    if( e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Up )
    {
        Thickness orig = MyGrid.Margin;
        MyGrid.Margin = new Thickness( margin.Left, margin.Up - 5, margin.Right, margin.Bottom );
    }
    else if( ... )
    ...
}
```

NOTE: You probably don't even need to allocate a new Thickness object.  Just change the one that is there.  This is purely for example's sake.

Comment: I tried that, but it "chews" the pixels from my grid after moving it. It doesn't leave the control intact after moving.

Comment: Lets say you are moving it down.  So that means you will be adding to the Up margin.  What side will get the pixels "chewed up"?  Is there enough space in the parent container for the move?

Comment: You might also try containing it in a Canvas.  That might be more flexible with the layout.

Comment: If I move the Grid down, then the down margin gets chewed up. I have put the Grid in a Canvas, but when I try to `Canvas.SetLeft(gridPlane1, 20.0);` it doesn't do anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think it worked. The problem was the function that I was setting the left and top properties. Moved the thing in a separate method and now it's just dandy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The way to move the grid depends on the container that it is contained in. If it is placed inside a Canvas then you can just bind the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties of the grid to some properties in your viewmodel and you can then change those numbers on up and down buttons like so:

```
<Canvas Width="400" Height="400">
    <Grid Height="20" Width="20" Canvas.Left="{Binding GridLeft}" Canvas.Top="{Binding GridTop}" Background="Red" />
</Canvas>
```

And ViewModel will be like this

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    int gridLeft;
    public int GridLeft
    {
        get { return gridLeft; }
        set 
        { 
            gridLeft = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GridLeft"));
        }
    }

    int gridTop;
    public int GridTop
    {
        get { return gridTop; }
        set 
        { 
            gridTop = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GridTop"));
        }
    }
}
```